# Radio buttons that hide a class dynamically

Tags: jquery

"You have not selected X" does not hide after a radio button has been selected.

script:

```
 $('input').live('change', function ()
 {
   if($('debt:radio:checked')) {
     $('.debt1').html('<span style="display:none"></span>');}
   if($('assets:radio:checked')) {
     $('.assets1').html('<span style="display:none"></span>');}
   if($('kids:radio:checked')) {
     $('.kids1').html('<span style="display:none"></span>');}
 });
```

html:

```
    Debt: <br />
    <input name="debt" type="radio" value="0" />
    <input name="debt" type="radio" value="-1" />
    <input name="debt" type="radio" value="-2" /><br />


    Kids:<br />
    <input name="kids" type="radio" value="0" />
    <input name="kids" type="radio" value="1" />
    <input name="kids" type="radio" value="3" /><br />


    Assets:<br />
    <input name="assets" type="radio" value="4" />
    <input name="assets" type="radio" value="5" />
    <input name="assets" type="radio" value="6" /><br />

    <br />

    <span class="debt1">You have not selected debt</span><br />
    <span class="kids1">You have not selected kids</span><br />
    <span class="assets1">You have not selected assets</span><br />
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJpRj/1/

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJpRj/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you didn't select jquery in your fiddle.

Then, your if statement needs to change a lot.

```
if($('debt:radio:checked')) {
```

Should be something more like this:

```
if($('input[name="debt"]:radio:checked').length > 0) {
```

Your code has a few issues.  First, the selector `debt:radio:checked`.  Just putting `dept` would match an element like `<dept></dept>`, not an input with the name dept.  And 2nd, `if($("..."))` will always return true, because jquery always returns an object.  You want to check if that object contains any elements, which is why I use `length`.

Comment: Thanks man for your help. I tested size, but length is what will work.

Comment: Also, `$('.debt1').hide()` should do.

Answer (score 2):

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/kkZDJ/1)**

CODE:

```
$('input').live('change', function() {
    if ( $('input[name=debt]:radio').is(':checked') ) {
        $('.debt1').html('');
    }
    if ( $('input[name=kids]:radio').is(':checked') ) {
        $('.kids1').html('');
    }
    if ( $('input[name=assets]:radio').is(':checked') ) {
        $('.assets1').html('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks roXon, that works great, a good way of doing it. I switched type to name (line 8).